# Get iframe with window.frames property vs. iframe ID

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I wonder why the following doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Iframe</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe name="myFrame"></iframe>
    <script>
        window.frames["myFrame"].style.background = "green";
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

However, if you access the iframe directly using its `ID`, it works with no problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Iframe</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe id="myFrame"></iframe>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("myFrame").style.background = "green";
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I use `window.frames` to get the first code to run properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work for you, because it will return the window object inside of the frame and not the iframe element. If you want to use the name attribute you can use `document.getElementsByName("myFrame")[0]` but I'd recommend accessing it by id.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to do a for loop to find all the frames and then access them by their index.

```
for(var i=0; i < frames.length; i++) {
    console.log(frames[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work the same for getElementsByName, mind you that it returns an array of element, not an element.

Both statements should have the same effect for frame with name of "myFrame", and id of "myFrame":

```
document.getElementsByName("myFrame")[0].style.background = "green";
document.getElementById("myFrame").style.background = "green";
```